# “Should I buy...” or “Should I purchase...”

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, word-difference

> 1. Should I buy/purchase web hosting?
> 2. Should I buy/purchase Adobe Photoshop?
> 3. Should I buy/purchase this car?
> 4. Should I buy/purchase this land?

When should I use *buy* and *purchase*? Why?

Comment: I have never heard someone say I don't purchase that opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In meaning, they're exactly the same. You can interchange fairly freely. Looking at the definitions on The [Free](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/buy) [Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/buy), each is used to define the other.

In practice, "purchase" is of a higher register than "buy", making it more formal. You might find "purchase" in a legal document, or regarding government expenditure, whereas "buy" is perhaps more for daily use.

The only other discernible difference I can think of is that "purchase" has the noun "purchase/s" whereas "buy" doesn't.

In your examples, simply consider the formality required for the context.

Comment: *Buy* can be a noun, but is ordinarily used as a noun only in certain financial contexts – a *buy* of stocks and bonds, for instance – and when we speak of something as being a *good buy* or a *best buy* in recommending a purchase. Otherwise, using *buy* as a noun usually indicates an effort to sound hip.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is true. I could have included that in my answer, but I added nouns as an afterthought, since the question was about verbs. Food for thought, though, thanks.

Comment: (+1, by the way; I was just supplementing a good answer.) I think you were entirely right to include the nouns. Many of the problems learners have arise because they are given "rules" or formulas which apply only in limited contexts. (I'm thinking particularly of the "baby rules" around perfect constructions, and the appalling "1st, 2nd 3rd" conditionals.) It is important to tell them when the rule you give them **stops** working, or you're just creating a future problem.

Comment: I agree with your point about learners being a bit "misled" by some rules. Nice feedback, thanks.

Comment: One other place where I might use _purchase_ instead of _buy_ is when using the words as a modifier. Someone working at a company might need to fill out a _purchase request form_ before buying Adobe Photoshop, for example. (I don't think I've every really heard of a _buy request form_, although, strictly speaking, English wouldn't forbid that.)